# Reset all the selected buttons color in Angular Table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a mat-table with column Plot which are mat-buttons.
I have developed the below code to toggle the individual row's button color when clicked.

.html

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Plot</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <button mat-icon-button aria-label="Example icon button with a heart icon">
        <mat-icon color=accent (click)="xyz(element)">
          <i class="fas fa-heart" [ngClass]="{'active': element.isActive}">preview</i>
        </mat-icon>
      </button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

.ts

```
xyz(turn) {
  turn.isActive = !turn.isActive;
}
```

Is there a way to reset the color of all the selected buttons at once when i click a button in a different Angular table ?

Or how to get the status(clicked or not) of all the buttons in the table ?

I searched for a way to reset all the button's color on many websites, but could not find a proper solution.

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an appropriate link @jenson-button-event